# How does image resizing work with css?

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I have been using css for a few years but have never ventured past using fixed width layouts. I'm looking at using a fluid layout for my next site, or as much percentage as I can, but I have a question that worries me.

If I have an image with 1900px width set as a background, I understand that it simply shrinks when the browser calls for say 1600px.

What happens when the resolution calls for a 2000px width? I will be left with white space, correct? How can one avoid this? I feel like I should probably just throw out that its not an image that can be repeated horizontally.

Comment: You can use media queries to swap the image out when the browser width is too large. The image tiles by default, but you can make it do whatever you want.

Comment: A 100% width will stretch your image to fill the space nicely.  No, I would very rarely suggest scaling an image up, but in the case of a background image and this situation, the likelihood of it stretching to the point of unacceptable distortion is slim to none if you're starting out with a 1900px wide image.  Supplement this with VKen's answer and you're set.

Comment: This is of almost no importance but the question is supposed to read "How does image re sizing work with css" not, "Hows does image re sizing with css?" sorry guys. its been a long day of computer-screen staring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trick usually used is to have the image be "inner-glowed" with a color, then set the background color the same as well.

Suppose your image doesn't tile, and has black "inner-glow" or "feather" effect, then you can make the container's background color as such:

```
background-color: #000;
background-image: url(your_bgimage.jpg); /* image with black borders due to effect */
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```